# amsmath: How can I use the equation numbering and label manually and anywhere?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath

I want to use the accustomed equation numbering and label manually and anywhere; for example in an array.

With the command 
`\newcommand{\tagx}[1][]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}` 
can I create custom tags `\tagx` or `\tagx[eq:bar]` and reference them as usual `\eqref{eq:bar}`.

But in a tag with an own figure 
`\newcommand\mytag[2][]{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\theequation}{#2}% ändern
(\theequation)\label{#1} % ausschreiben
\endgroup
}` 
still works `\mytag[eq:bar1]{***}`, but not the referencing `\eqref{eq:bar1}`.

What can I do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\newcommand{\tagx}[1][]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}

\newcommand\mytag[2][]{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\theequation}{#2}% ändern
(\theequation)\label{#1} % ausschreiben
\endgroup
}

% \renewcommand{\theequation}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:foo1} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo1}.

\section{Putting a tag in the text}
A normal tag in the text \tagx[eq:bar0] and an own tag \mytag[eq:bar1]{***} is showing correct. 

The referencing of the normal tag in the text \eqref{eq:bar0} is correct; but the own tag \eqref{eq:bar1} is wrong - here should be "(***)". 
\bigskip


Another equation:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:foo2} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using `\theequation`  in `\mytag` ? also shouldn't the argument to `\tagx` be mandatory not optional?  If you omit the argument then you will execute `\label{}`  which doesn't really work (and will give errors if done more than once)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought it would be better to keep the label name optional. So `\tagx` gives (1.2) e.g. And `\tagx[eq:foo]` gives (1.2) and sets `\label{eq:foo}`.    I do not think I have to label all tagx'es there ever will be.

Comment: in that case you would only want to do the `\label` in the case the argument was  provided, as it is above if you don't supply the option you end up with `\label{}` which is an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed your solution to `% \tagx[<label, optional>]   % normal tag inline
\newcommand{\tagx}[1][]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}`

That is wrong?

Comment: yes that is wrong as you do `\label{}` if the argument is not provided.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Ok, I saw: with `\label{}` I can yield `LaTeX Warning: Label ' multiply defined.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\mytag` command doesn't set `\@currentlabel`.

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytag[2][]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
  (#2)\label{#1}% ausschreiben
}
\makeatother
```

I'm not sure why the “label” argument is optional: you *need* it, don't you?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\tagx}[1][]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytag[2][]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
  (#2)\label{#1} % ausschreiben
}
\makeatother

% \renewcommand{\theequation}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:foo1} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo1}.

\section{Putting a tag in the text}
A normal tag in the text \tagx[eq:bar0] and an own tag \mytag[eq:bar1]{***} is showing correct. 

The referencing of the normal tag in the text \eqref{eq:bar0} is correct; but the own tag \eqref{eq:bar1} is wrong - here should be "(***)". 
\bigskip


Another equation:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:foo2} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd implement it differently: the label should be mandatory and the personal tag optional.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, xparse}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tagx}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% normal equation number
    \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#2}%
   }
   {% personal tag
    (#1)\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:foo1} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo1}.

\section{Putting a tag in the text}
A normal tag in the text \tagx{eq:bar0} and an own 
tag \tagx[***]{eq:bar1} is showing correct. 

The referencing of the normal tag in the text \eqref{eq:bar0} 
is correct; the own tag \eqref{eq:bar1} is correct as well.

Another equation:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:foo2} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see: you put both commands together.

Comment: @ egreg  Is it possible, to make the label-name ('eq:bar1' e.g.) an optional argument too?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\newcommand{\tagx}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytag[2]{{%
#2%
\def\@currentlabel{#2}%
\label{#1}%
}}
\makeatother
% \renewcommand{\theequation}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:foo1} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo1}.

\section{Putting a tag in the text}
A normal tag in the text \tagx{eq:bar0} and an own tag \mytag{eq:bar1}{***} is showing correct. 

The referencing of the normal tag in the text \eqref{eq:bar0} is correct; but the own tag \eqref{eq:bar1} is wrong - here should be "(***)". 
\bigskip


Another equation:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:foo2} 
\end{equation}
The tag of the equation is \eqref{eq:foo2}.

\end{document}
```