# amsmath: How to make inline tags, with and without labels?

Tags: amsmath, labels

I have a follow-up question to [@egregs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491625/amsmath-how-can-i-use-the-equation-numbering-and-label-manually-and-anywhere?noredirect=1#comment1241416_491625):

At the command

```
\usepackage{xparse}
% \tagx[shown text, optional]{label-name}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tagx}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% normal equation number
    \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#2}%
   }
   {% personal tag
    (#1)\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
   }%
}
\makeatother
```

I have to set a label-name at all time: `\tagx{label-name}`. 
Without an optional tag-name (`\tagx[eq *]{label-name}` ---> `(eq *)`)  this will give the current equation number, *(1.2)* e.g.

How can I make the labeling (and the shown text) optionally, like

```
\tagx[name={eq ***}, label=foo]
```

**MWE:** 
`(with LaTeX Warning: Label  multiply defined.)`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\usepackage{xparse}
% \tagx[shown text, optional]{label-name}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tagx}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% normal equation number
    \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#2}%
   }
   {% personal tag
    (#1)\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % for highlighting
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:bar1} 
\end{equation}

\bigskip
This is an inline-tag \tagx{foo1}, it is also labeled \eqref{foo1}.

This is a personalized inline-tag \tagx[***]{foo2}, it is also labeled \eqref{foo2}.

\bigskip
This is an inline-tag \tagx{}, it is \emph{not} labeled.

This is a personalized inline-tag \tagx[***]{}, it is \emph{not} labeled.

\bigskip
An another equation: 
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:bar2} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps `xkeyval` or `pgfkeys`?

Comment: @Symbol1 `pgfkeys` is a good advice, but I can not throw that together with xparse.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a direct copy from my answer on [texwelt.de](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/24817/anwenden-von-pgfkeys-in-einem-xparse-befehl-fur-referenzierte-und-personalisierte-tags-und-labels/24826).

It is a pure LaTeX3 implementation utilizing the `l3keys` module. Instead of `l3keys` one could use `pgfkeys` quite easily by defining the options in `\pgfkeys` instead of `\keys_define:nn` and using `\pgfkeys` to set them instead of `\keys_set:nn`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\usepackage{xparse} % lädt auch `expl3`

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { cis / tagx }
  {
    ,label .tl_set:N = \l__cis_tagx_label_tl
    ,name  .tl_set:N = \l__cis_tagx_name_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \tagx { O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { cis / tagx } { #1 }
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__cis_tagx_name_tl
      {
        \refstepcounter{equation}
        ( \theequation )
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l__cis_tagx_label_tl
          { \exp_args:NV \label \l__cis_tagx_label_tl }
      }
      {
        ( \l__cis_tagx_name_tl )
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l__cis_tagx_label_tl
          {
            \tl_set_eq:NN \@currentlabel \l__cis_tagx_name_tl
            \exp_args:NV \label \l__cis_tagx_label_tl
          }
      }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
An equation for counting: 
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:bar1} 
\end{equation}

\bigskip
This is an inline-tag \tagx[label=foo1], it is also labeled \eqref{foo1}.

This is a personalized inline-tag \tagx[name=***,label=foo2], it is also labeled \eqref{foo2}.

\bigskip
This is an inline-tag \tagx, it is \emph{not} labeled.

This is a personalized inline-tag \tagx[name=***], it is \emph{not} labeled.

\bigskip
An another equation: 
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:bar2} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```